# Hide other shipping methods if avialaible one

Tags: php, woocommerce, shipping-method

I Want To hide rates if DHL is Avialaible.

DHL value is **flat_rate:7**.
want to hide another rate with value **flat_rate:8** and **flat_rate:9**.
i have alredy unset flat rate8 but want to unset both of them.

```
function filter_woocommerce_rates( $rates, $package ) { 
  
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        
        if ( in_array( $rate_id, array( 'flat_rate:7' ) ) ) {
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:8']);
        } 
    }   
    
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
    //Hide Shipping rates if one is avialaible
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) { 
    // ids of shipping methods
     $method_ids = array('39', '69');
    
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // targeting flat rate method
        if( '55' === $rate->method_id || in_array($rate->id, $method_ids) ) {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
    }   
    
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Tested and Working !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).